# Centering caption for a double column figure

Tags: captions

I am writing a paper in IEEEtran class (Michael Shell) . I have a figure which fits in the two columns. But thee caption is being left aligned. How shall I center the caption? Should we center a caption for IEEEtran class ?  MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{myfig2.png}
    \caption{Simulink model }
    \label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an MWE.

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100434/centering-figure-captions-in-ieeetran?rq=1) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164719/ieeetran-centering-double-column-figure-captions?rq=1).

Comment: welcome to tex.se! and please provide small, complete document (mwe), which show your problem.

Comment: I saw those 2 questions but could not understand what to do. Are the ieee class captions left aligned even for a double column figure?

Comment: @Shivam, yes, default caption position in `IEEEtran˛` is left aligned. if you will publish in their conference/journal, than left this as it is. otherwise use solution in provided links.

Comment: Ok. So I will leave it left aligned. Thanks